# Building dynamic if statement based on user-defined input

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table, with increasing values each row (year in the code below).
I have a target, that specifies a "threshold". The target is user defined, it can contain a value for one or multiple columns of the table. This means you never know how many columns are specified in the target.
I want to match the first row in the table, where the values in the row are greater than the values in the target. I currently have this:

```
class Target < ActiveRecord::Base

  def loop_sheets(sheets, year_array)
    result = nil
    elements = self.class.column_names[1..-3].map(&:to_sym)
    to_match = elements.select{|e| self.send(e) != nil }
    condition = to_match.map do |attr|
      "row[:#{attr}] > #{attr}"
    end.join " and "
    year_array.each do |year|
      sheets.each do |sheet|
        row = sheet.calculation.datatable.select { |r| r[:year] == year }.first
        does_match = eval(condition)
        if does_match 
          result = {
            :year => row[:year],
            :sheet_name => sheet.name
          }
          return result
        end
      end
    end
    return result
  end

end
```

This works perfectly, but now the algorithm is fixed to use AND matching. I want to support OR matching as well as AND matching. Also I want to avoid using eval, there has to be a more elegant way. Also I want to reduce the complexity of this code as much as possible.
How could I rewrite this code to meet these requirements? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid using `eval`: Ruby can create code dynamically, so do that instead of adding strings together. All you have to do is take the strings away!

```
conditions = to_match.map do |attr|
  proc {|row| row[attr.to_sym] > attr }
end
```

Now you have an array of runnable blocks that take the `row` as their argument and return the result of the condition (`return` keyword not required). If you're just doing `and`, it's as simple as:

```
does_match = conditions.all? {|c| c.call(row) }
```

which will be `true` only if *all* the conditions return a truthy value (i.e. not `false` or `nil`).

---

As for supporting OR logic, if you are happy to just support ORing all of the conditions (e.g. replacing "and" with "or") then this will do it:

```
does_match = conditions.any? {|c| c.call(row) }
```

but if you want to support ORing some and ANDing others, you'll need someway to group them together, which is more complex.

Comment: Thanks for this, it achieves all requirements and more. I will give it a try.